# Mongoose Document.toObject produces GraphQL error

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I am using [`mongoose`](https://mongoosejs.com/) and [`express-graphql`](https://npm.im/express-graphql) together in a project. I want to convert a document to an object using the `.toObject()` method described [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) and then return the value to GraphQL.

GraphQL Schema:

```
type User {
    _id: ID,
    // ...
}
```

Code:

```
const Me = function (params, req) {
    if (!req.user) throw Error('Not logged in');
    return req.user.toObject();
};

module.exports = Me;
```

However, I get the following error:

> ID cannot represent value: { _bsontype: "ObjectID", id: < Buffer 5b 9b cb 54 df d9 c5 1e 04 e4 eb 54> }

I have tried printing the `_id` to screen using `console.log(req.user.toObject()._id)`, but it simply shows the id string. For some reason, the following code works:

```
const Me = function (params, req) {
    if (!req.user) throw Error('Not logged in');
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user.toObject()));
};

module.exports = Me;
```

I am not sure what is causing GraphQL to read the `_id` field as a non-string value straight from the `.toObject()` method. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the graphql version?

Comment: @ShivamPandey GraphQL 14.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `14.0.2` which has an issue by [a change](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/1382) to the graphql package introduced in latest release and there is [already a PR](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/1520) which solves this problem. So better if you switch to `0.13.2` which works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to temporarily patch the issue by setting `user._id = String(user._id)` after calling `.toObject()`.